# Why graphs / graph based algorithms?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Not sure if this is more related to computer science but, at first, I think a graph is a quite fundamental object in maths so I will try it first here:

Why do some (or a lot) algorithms utilize graphs? I'm quite familiar with graphs and the underlying framework but I just wonder if there is a (mathematical) reason which make them better suited?
I can understand that when people implement an algorithm on different ways and figure out a graph structure is more promising - but nevertheless I feel graphs are quite popular for several reasons and not only because they provide the best results. There are probably more "theoretical" reasons I assume?
Are there?

Comment: If you ever find yourself dabbling in foundations of math or automated theorem proving, you’ll find that from a certain perspective, a well-kept secret in maths is that *basically everything* is induction — and it just so happens that trees are the most natural way of representing inductive structures, and it’s also relatively easy to do induction on graphs in general.

Comment: If you want to learn more about the way we use inductive types to formalise, well, most things in math, I recommend checking out this interactive online tutorial in the theorem proving language Lean: https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/. You’ll see that Boolean structures with “true”, “false”, “and”, and “or” are all just built up inductively. The natural numbers are a sort of tree where each node only has one child. Most concepts in math can be built up as inductive datatypes, which are implicitly very “tree-like”.

Comment: "Why do some (or a lot) algorithms utilize graphs?" - Can you give two examples? Offhand, I can't think of an algorithm which uses graphs to accomplish something that isn't inherently graph-related.

Comment: Many algorithms' formulations are not set, at first glance, using graphs, but all of them rely on recursion (or induction, which is the same), which yield to dependencies upon values; mathematically modeled with graphs. And then, it is easier to solve them as graph properties are well known and studied.

Comment: I like this question and I hope for some interesting answers. I suspect that there is an analogy between graphs and manifolds. Like, a graph might be viewed as a discrete version of a manifold. The graph Laplacian would be part of this analogy. Perhaps just as a smooth manifold is the natural setting to do calculus, perhaps a graph is a natural setting to do finite-difference calculus. I don't know the extent to which this is a valid analogy.

Comment: @TannerSwett That's a bit imprecise. Think about dynamic programming... Many problems are efficiently solved with DP where graphs may not be obvious to be considered as a solution (i.e. justifying text, knapsack, edit distance...). And DP is just applying DAGs techniques to non-graph related problems.

Comment: For the same reason Network Science is a thing: because in a lot of cases, what's interesting is not necessarily the objects themselves but the relationships between them. See also category theory.

Comment: To offer @TannerSwett two examples, I would offer solving the optimal assignment problem with the Kuhn-Munkres algorithm and using rooted trees with weighted nodes to find perfect play in game theory.  These two examples demonstrate some of the strengths of modeling with graphs.  Bipartite graphs with weighted edges can effectively describe the strength of a relationship between members of two different sets, and rooted trees or directed graphs can describe the states of a discrete "process" (a term I am using very informally) as it changes over various iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is largely based on the problem, and there are plenty of interesting problems unrelated to graphs. But, from a computer science standpoint, I would argue that graphs are of particular interest as a powerful data structure which encapsulates  other data structures as special cases.

Data structures store elements and, at best, a rudimentary order or relation of those elements. For example: (1) an ascending order of elements in an array or linked list, or (2) a parent/child relationship maintained by a tree.
A graph stores elements as nodes and additionally edge objects give the ability to store any number of relation between elements, as well as varying types of relations since edges themselves can hold information (such as weight, ID, and other attributes). In this sense, linked-lists are a special kind of graph where each element is a node and has an unweighted edge to the node before/after it. Similarly, a tree is a particular kind of graph where each element has an unweighted edge to a parent and all children elements. A graph then allows for a great degree of freedom when describing how elements are related.